# Unwrapped non-optional in Swift

Tags: swift, option-type

> "String?" - means optional string,
>
> "String!" - means implicitly unwrapped optional string.

What do you call "String" as a type, without a `?` or `!` at the end?

Reason why I was asking:

when reading the swift documentation on the different types (`?` and `!`), I could not see whether implicitly unwrapped optionals are "String" or "String!".

I know now. So either the documentation could be clearer, or a dedicated name for a plain "String" would help.

Comment: A `String` is a `String`... What do you expect?

Comment: Not everything has to be an optional.

Comment: In a meeting, I can imagine a case where someone says you should use a String. Someone else says "Optional?". You say no, not an optional, not an implicitly unwrapped, just a plain one. Long-winded. Could get a simple name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A String without a ? or ! at end is just a String. It's not a kind of optional.

Comment: I think it would be better if there was a name for it. Thanks.

Comment: @RowanGontier It does have a name - `String`. There is `String`, optional `String` (with `?`), and implicitly unwrapped `String` (with `!`).

Comment: Okay, fair enough.